# TCPDF - printing table from mysql

Tags: php, tcpdf

in my php,

```
while($info3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
$Name = $info3["Name"];
$Address = $info3["Address"];
$Age = $info3["Age"];
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
$tbl = '
<table style="width: 638px;" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 150px;">'.$Name.'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 378px;">'.$Age.'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 110px; text-align:center">'.$Address.'</td>
    </tr>
</table>
';

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
}
```

Prints the whole table always in my pdf. But I want to print `<table>` and `</table>` for a single instance and then want to loop printing the rows in between. How can I solve this??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$tbl_header = '<table style="width: 638px;" cellspacing="0">';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';
$tbl = '';

// foreach item in your array...
$tbl .= '
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 150px;">'.$Name.'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 378px;">'.$Age.'</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 110px; text-align:center">'.$Address.'</td>
    </tr>
';

$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you mean is you want one table that includes all the results as rows, only loop the row printing and migrate the opening and closing tags outside the loop.

```
$tbl = '<table style="width: 638px;" cellspacing="0">';

    while($info3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
    $Name = $info3["Name"];
    $Address = $info3["Address"];
    $Age = $info3["Age"];

    $tbl .= '<tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 150px;">'.$Name.'</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 378px;">'.$Age.'</td>
            <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 110px; text-align:center">'.$Address.'</td>
            </tr>'
     }
$tbl .= '</table>';


$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

Comment: not working.. This displays only a single row.. and i am getting result only if `$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');` is inside the loop

Comment: @blasteralfred - can you edit in your SQL statement so we can be certain it is fetching multiple rows?

Comment: even without sql, in a simple look, it stucks using dummy data.. I found andre's answer useful.. But still I am looking for a suggestion like Deacon's

Answer (score 2):

I would certainly do something like this:

```
$table = '<table style="width: 638px;" cellspacing="0">%s</table>'
$tr    = '
    <tr>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 150px;"> %s</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 378px;"> %s</td>
        <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 110px; text-align:center">%s</td>
    </tr>
';

while($info3 =  = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
    $trs[] = sprintf($tr, $info3["Name"], $info3["Age"], $info3["Address"]);
}

$tbl = sprintf($table, implode( $trs ));
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```

If you can't organize your presentation layer with templates at least make it as separated as you can from the actual logic.

You can [read about sprintf here](http://pt2.php.net/sprintf) and [implode here](http://pt2.php.net/implode)

Answer (score 0):

```
$tbl = '<table style="width: 638px;" cellspacing="0">';
while($info3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
  $Name = $info3["Name"];
  $Address = $info3["Address"];
  $Age = $info3["Age"];
  // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $tbl = $tbl . '<tr>
          <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 150px;">'.$Name.'</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 378px;">'.$Age.'</td>
          <td style="border: 1px solid #000000; width: 110px; text-align:center">'.$Address.'</td>
      </tr>';
  }  
  $tbl = $tbl . '</table>';
  $pdf->writeHTML($tbl, true, false, false, false, '');
```