# outputting table using fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I am trying to output a table using `FPDF` and PHP.

What I need is to output the table headings and I have a doctrine (symfony) collection.

I'm using the `writeHTML` method using:

```
$pdf->writeHTML('<table>','','','','');
$pdf->writeHTML('<tr><th>Tooth Selection</th><th>Requirements</th><th>Shade</th><th>Cost</th></tr>','','','','');
$order_items = $this->order_details->getIncludedItemsOrders();
  foreach($order_items as $item)
  {
    $pdf->writeHTML('<tr><td>Test1</td><td>Test2</td><td>Test3</td><td>test4</td></tr>', '','');
  }

 $pdf->writeHTML('</table>');
```

But I get errors, such as:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: cols in
 Notice: Undefined variable: cellspacingx in
```

Am I doing this correct as I can't find much information regarding outputting tables using a `foreach`

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's FPDF for you. It's full of code that raises E_NOTICE errors. If you need to stay with FPDF, you need to turn E_NOTICE off.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);
```

I'd recommend moving to a newer and better amintained library like [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) though.

Comment: Found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261684/tcpdf-printing-table-from-mysql which seems to help me

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the upper comment. 
Either disable the errors or even better... FIX them. If some content is already generated you will not be able to set the pdf headers. Though you can still save the pdf to a file.

I have my own fpdf table script: http://interpid.eu/fpdf-table